# Maximum of a Rayleigh quotient with non-Euclidean inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It's well known that, for a real and symmetric matrix $A$,
$$
  \max_v \frac { (Av,v) } {(v,v)} = \lambda_{\max}(A).
$$

Now I'm looking at generalized Rayleigh quotients of the form
$$
  R = \max_v \frac { (Bv,v)_A } {(v,v)_A},
$$
where $A$ is symmetric positive definite and $B$ a square matrix of the same size. I use the notation $(u,v)_A = (Au,v)$ for the $A$-inner product.
If we assume that $B$ is self-adjoint in the $A$-inner product, then it has real eigenvalues.

By playing with matrix square roots, we can easily rewrite this quotient as
$$
  R = \max_w \frac { (A^{1/2} B A^{-1/2} w,w) } {(w,w)},
$$
and if this matrix were symmetric, we would immediately obtain from the result on classical Rayleigh quotients as well as a similarity transformation that
$$
 R = \lambda_{\max}(A^{1/2} B A^{-1/2}) = \lambda_{\max}(B).
$$
However, there is no reason to assume that the matrix $A^{1/2} B A^{-1/2}$ is symmetric.

So my question is: can we still get a result of the type $R = \lambda_{\max}(B)$ or something similar? Are any additional assumptions on $B$ required? Any references on this topic?

Comment: I figured out the answer to my own question soon after posting and left an answer below.

Comment: I know this is not part of the question, but exactly how d you show the first formula? Do you know any resource?

Comment: @Euler_Salter: the one about the maximum eigenvalue? It's a standard result you can find in any linear algebra textbook. It's even on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the matrix I was talking about is indeed symmetric under the stated assumptions. We have
$$
  (A^{1/2} B A^{-1/2})^\top
  = A^{-1/2} B^\top A^{1/2}
  = A^{-1/2} B^\top A A^{-1/2}
  = A^{-1/2} A B A^{-1/2}
  = A^{1/2} B A^{-1/2}.
$$
Here we used $B^\top A = (AB)^\top = AB$, i.e., that $B$ is self-adjoint w.r.t. $A$.

So, in short, the result
$$
  R = \lambda_{\max}(B)
$$
holds true in this case.